# Facebook SDK for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm a bit confused, in my last project I used Facebook sdk, I did that by downloading the project [facebook / facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), and adding the `src` folder to my project.

Then I imported the FBConnect.h header to my code and used the `FBConnect` object to connect.

Now I see there is this [Facebook SDK for iOS](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/) that I can install, and then use `FBSession` object to connect.

Is this new? what is the different between the two? 
A short explanation will be appreciate :)

Comment: This is fairly new, it seems to work quite different too.  It was released earlier this month (August 7). There seems to be a few bugs associated with this release version though. Here's a link to the new features https://developers.facebook.com/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3/

Answer (score 0):

FBSession stores your access_token and some other information about the user once the user has logged in. If I'm not mistaken it conforms to a Singleton Pattern so you don't create and instance of it, instead you call the class methods to get to certain objects, like the access_token.

You can still use the old classes since it ships with the Facebook.h and FBConnect.h in the new SDK under deprecated headers. And you can replace everything in that folder with the new since it conforms to both the old and new SDK. Although this is perhaps not recommended since they are, as the name implies, deprecated. But they work really good as is right now.